# weblogic setting log filename pattern for rotation

Tags: logging, weblogic, wlst

I have written a wlst script to change the log file rotation strategy from BySize to ByTime which works correctly but the names of the rotated files are still fileName.log000n where n is a number.

I would like to have a datestamp in the rotated filenames instead. I didn't find any way to do this. Neither from the admin console nor with wlst.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to set the timestamp in the name of the file.

From http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/logging/RotateLogFiles.html

> To include a time and date stamp in
>   the file name when the log file is
>   rotated, in the File Name field, add
>   java.text.SimpleDateFormat  variables
>   to the file name and surround each
>   variable with percentage (%)
>   characters.
>
> For example, if you enter the
>   following value in the File Name
>   field:
>   myserver_%yyyy%*%MM%*%dd%*%hh%*%mm%.log,
>   the server's log file will be named:
>   myserver_yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm.log.
>
> When the server instance rotates the
>   log file, the rotated file name
>   contains the date stamp. For example,
>   if the server instance rotates its
>   local log file on 4 March, 2005 at
>   10:15 AM, the log file that contains
>   the old log messages will be named:
>   myserver_2005_03_04_10_15.log.
>
> If you do not include a time and date
>   stamp, the rotated log files are
>   numbered in order of creation
>   filenamennnnn, where filename is the
>   name configured for the log file. For
>   example: myserver.log00007